Add new Data Source to Spring Boot 2.6.2 JdbcTemplate
I have an existing Spring Boot 2.6.2 microservice that we want to add a call to a new data source. This is being deployed to Openliberty 23.0.0.10 with Java 8. I created a new DAO:
public class iSeriesDatabaseDao {

       @Autowired
       private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

       public String getPhoneNumber(String number)
                                    throws SSOServiceException {

                try {
                       String sqlString = String.join(" ",
                            "SELECT phone AS SPECIALITY, (wrkph1 CONCAT wrkph2 CONCAT wrkph3) AS PHONE FROM PRVMAS where PROVNO = '%s'");
                       String getPhone = String.format(sqlString,number);
                       return String.valueOf(jdbcTemplate.queryForList(getPhone));

                   } catch (Exception e) {
                         throw new SSOServiceException("Error in the query the 
                   configuration table: " + e.getMessage());

                  }
              }

I have updated my server.xml to account for the new JDBC driver and data source connection.
              <jdbcDriver id="DB2iSeries">
                             <library name="DB2iToolboxLib">
                                           <fileset dir="${wlp.user.dir}/shared/resources" includes="jt400.jar" />
                             </library>
              </jdbcDriver>

<dataSource jdbcDriverRef="DB2iSeries" jndiName="jdbc/iSeriesDataSource">
    <properties serverName="${env.DB_ISERIES_URL}" password="${env.DB_ISERIES_PWD}" user="${env.DB_USERID}" />
</dataSource>

I also updated my application.properties file too.
spring.datasource.jndi-name=jdbc/PostgresSQLDataSource
spring.datasource.jndi-name-iSeries=jdbc/iSeriesDataSource

I am getting the following error message when I test my code.
[ERROR   ] Connection error:
SSL error: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
[ERROR   ] Failed to create a ConnectionPoolDataSource from PostgreSQL JDBC Driver 42.1.4 for user_xxx at jdbc:postgresql://Dev.xxx.com:3306/xxx?prepareThreshold=5&preparedStatementCacheQueries=256&preparedStatementCacheSizeMiB=5&databaseMetadataCacheFields=65536&databaseMetadataCacheFieldsMiB=5&defaultRowFetchSize=0&binaryTransfer=true&readOnly=false&binaryTransferEnable=&binaryTransferDisable=&unknownLength=2147483647&logUnclosedConnections=false&disableColumnSanitiser=false&ssl=true&tcpKeepAlive=false&loginTimeout=0&connectTimeout=10&socketTimeout=0&cancelSignalTimeout=10&receiveBufferSize=-1&sendBufferSize=-1&ApplicationName=PostgreSQL JDBC Driver&useSpnego=false&gsslib=auto&sspiServiceClass=POSTGRES&allowEncodingChanges=false&targetServerType=any&loadBalanceHosts=false&hostRecheckSeconds=10&preferQueryMode=extended&autosave=never&reWriteBatchedInserts=false: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: SSL error: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
              at org.postgresql.ssl.MakeSSL.convert(MakeSSL.java:67)
              at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.enableSSL(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:359)
              at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:148)
              at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:49)
              at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:194)
              at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:450)

This references the PostgreSQL database which is an existing connection, not my new connection. The PostgreSQL connection is working fine. What additional changes are needed to set up the new iSeries connection?

You should setup the environment. Complain about SSL tells you don't specify neede parameters. Why connection becomes SSL aware depends on server envorinment, see https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ssl-tcp.html Also I want warn that creating query by naive using String.format() is not secure. You should use prepared statement with needed parameters.

The issue was the cert wasn't imported so I used the Keystone Explorer and added the cert. I have multiple JDKs on this machine when I checked the first time I missed the additional JDK that needed the cert.
